# Get rectangles from a 2d array of tiles

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, rectangles

I basically want to convert this input:

```
var tiles:Array = new Array();

tiles[0] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
tiles[1] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0];
tiles[2] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
tiles[3] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
tiles[4] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
tiles[5] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
tiles[6] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
tiles[7] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
tiles[8] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
tiles[9] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
```

To this output (a vector of rectangles) :

```
[
    (x=0, y=0, w=4, h=2),
    (x=5, y=1, w=3, h=1),
    (x=5, y=2, w=1, h=2),
    (x=2, y=5, w=1, h=1),
    (x=5, y=6, w=5, h=4)
]
```

Also it cant be overlapping rectangles and it can be in any layout not only the one i gave.

I have been looking for code samples in as3 or algorithms but they are always on other programming languages or to complicated to implement, so i hope somebody here already has had the same problem.

EDIT: As @Marty suggested, another answer could be working the other way around, providing the rectangles and getting the array as output, I will try to get it working and put it as an answer (if nobody get it working first) but i hope it can be done the first way.

Comment: This is an interesting question - if it's possible, it would be much easier to do the other way around (provide rectangles and get that output) if all you need to do is have both one way or another. Also, this can become extremely complicated if you want to handle input where the are holes (e.g. set `tiles[0][1]` to `0` - there are multiple rectangle layouts to choose from).

Comment: actually giving rectangles and getting the array sounds like is a very good idea, but what do you think is a good way for doing that? or do i have to make another question?

Comment: Maybe just edit this question to note you're happy having it work the other way around instead (although this comment thread will achieve the same thing anyway).

Comment: As @Marty pointed out, the original question needs clarification regarding what to do when multiple answers are possible. This is already the case in your given example, where we can have (x=5, y=1, w=1, h=3) instead of your given answer.

Comment: I would also add whether overlapping rectangles are OK or not - I assume not.

Comment: In my case the rectangle layouts really doesn't matter as iam using them for aabb collision only and it would work either way, so any combination of rectangles that fill the 1's in the array will work for me.

Comment: Thinking about this even more, I think the correct solution would be the one that generates the *least* amount of rectangles which do not overlap. What do you think?

Comment: I think that will be the best solution, but also will over complicate the algorithm where i don't really need the least amount of rectangles i only need enough rectangles for filling the 1's and even a not so efficient layout will do it. But i also think that an algorithm that gets the least amount of rectangles will benefit more people. you think i should update the question if that's the case?

Comment: Triangles are outside of my capabilities mathematically given *any* convex shape with three vertices is considered one.

Comment: Sorry, i putted triangles when i meaned rectangles. I edited it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try work on the solution for your initial problem, but for now if you want to convert some input Rectangles to a 2D array, you can try this function I've made:

```
function rectanglesToArray(input:Vector.<Rectangle>):Array
{
    var r:Rectangle;
    var gwidth:int = 0;
    var gheight:int = 0;

    // Determine the width and height of the grid.
    for each(r in input)
    {
        gwidth = Math.max(r.x + r.width, gwidth);
        gheight = Math.max(r.y + r.height, gheight);
    }


    // Define empty cells.
    var output:Array = [];
    for(var i:int = 0; i < gheight; i++)
    {
        output[i] = [];

        for(var j:int = 0; j < gwidth; j++)
            output[i].push(0);
    }

    // Define filled rectangles.
    for each(r in input)
    {
        for(var column:int = r.x; column < r.x + r.width; column++)
        {
            for(var row:int = r.y; row < r.y + r.height; row++)
            {
                output[row][column] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

With a small demo:

```
var result:Array = rectanglesToArray(new <Rectangle>[
    new Rectangle(0, 0, 4, 2),
    new Rectangle(5, 1, 3, 1),
    new Rectangle(5, 2, 1, 2),
    new Rectangle(2, 5, 1, 1),
    new Rectangle(5, 6, 5, 4)
]);

trace(result.join("\n"));
```

Which gives the output:

```
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: O god you are fast!. This function works so perfect that now i will have to trow away the one that i made haha. I will still wait for answers to the first question do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an enormously difficult problem, but it sure is an interesting one. You could write a function that identifies a rectangle given coordinates for the beginning of the rectangle, and that function could then call a function that alters the grid and zeroes out the ones that are contained in the rectangle. Then it would just be a matter of iterating over the grid. In C-esque pseudo code:

```
var grid = {{0, 0, 0....}}
var output = {}

function examine_rectangle(x, y) {
    var w = 1
    var h = 1

    while (grid[y][x + w] == 1) {
        w += 1
    }

    var i = 0

    while (grid[y + h][x + i] == 1) {
        if (i == w - 1) {
            i = 0
            h += 1
        } else {
            i += 1
        }
    }

    output.push({x, y, w, h})

    clean_rectangle(x, y, w, h)
}

function clean_rectangle(x, y, w, h) {
    var i = 0

    while (i < w) i += 1) {
        var j = 0

        while (j < h) {
            grid[y + j][x + i] = 0
            j += 1
        }

        i += 1
    }
}

var x = 0

while (x < grid[0].size()) {
    var y = 0

    while(y < grid.size()) {
        if (grid[y][x] == 1) {
            examine_rectangle(x, y)
        }

        y += 1
    }

    x += 1
}

// yey! now we have got our answer in the output array
```